# Synonym for prostrating on the ground, typically in worship or submission, starts with 'g'

Tags: synonyms

I've looked for synonyms for prostrate, lie etc. but nothing has stirred my memory of this exotic word that reminds me of 'gastrification' for some reason. Said word also has a 'p' in it somewhere... probably.

Comment: lol can someone comment what is unclear instead of downvoting multiple times? i haven't edited yet, please let me know what is unclear, question has been answered but it will help me when asking more questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [**genuflect**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genuflection)?

> Genuflection (or genuflexion), bending at least one knee to the ground, was from early times a gesture of deep respect for a superior.  The Latin word *genuflectio*, from which the English word is derived, originally meant kneeling rather than the rapid dropping to one knee and immediately rising that became customary in Western Europe in the Middle Ages.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're not thinking of ***grovel***

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grovel)) defines it as:

> 1 to creep with the face to the ground :  crawl
>
> 2a to lie or creep with the body prostrate in token of subservience or abasement

Comment: thank you for this, i'm surprised i forgot 'grovel'. although this answer is a perfect candidate, i marked the one with 'genuflect' since that was the word i couldn't recall in the first place.